# Customizing Django Admin's verbose_name by init, using default

Tags: django, django-admin

As I would use in version 2 of django the
`default_app_config = 'catalog.apps.CatalogConfig'` in `__init__` to set `verbose_name` and customize django admin? It returns the error

> 'No Module named catalog'

Details: I use my apps to a directory below and in `INSTALLED_APPS` I put `projectName.AppName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't much clear (*to me*). What I understood is, you tried to customize the admin interface by adding `verbose_name` and during that process you got the error, `'No Module named catalog'`.
If that so,
Initial you have to put the **`verbose_name`** name in your `apps configuration` class inside the **`apps`** module

```
# catalog/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CatalogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'catalog'
    verbose_name = 'Fantasy Title'
```

and in your **`INSTALLED_APPS`** of `settings.py`, it should be either

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'catalog',
    .....
]
```

**OR**

```
 
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'catalog.apps.CatalogConfig',
    .....
]
```